# Title of Subplots in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to make a grid of 3x3 subplots in Plotly. I'm trying to get titles for each subplot and a main title on the top and I can't seem to get it to work. 
I see this [wonderful site](http://takwatanabe.me/data_science/plotly_layout/plotly-layout-options-subplots.html) for Python but I can't seem to find its equivalent for R.

```
all <- subplot(graph1, graph2, graph3, graph4, graph5, graph6, 
graph7, graph8, graph9, nrows = 3)
```

That gave me the grid I wanted but don't have the titles I want on the subplots:

```
1. Graph 1 
2. Graph 2
3. Graph 3
4. Graph 4
5. Graph 5
6. Graph 6
7. Graph 7
8. Graph 8 
9. Graph 9
```

and the the default Main Title was Graph 9.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give subtitles for subplot in plot\_ly using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285729/how-to-give-subtitles-for-subplot-in-plot-ly-using-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use ggplot + plotly to achieve it. This does the trick:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

mtcars$main1 = "title1"
mtcars$main2 = "title2"

p1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~main1) 
p2 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = hp)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~main2) 

plotly::subplot(p1, p2 ,nrows = 1, margin = 0.23 ) %>% layout(title ="Main title")
```

[image]