# Merging legends in plotly subplot

Tags: r, plotly, legend, subplot, r-plotly

I have several groups where for each I have several classes for which I measured continuous values:

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(value = c(rnorm(100,1,1), rnorm(100,2,1), rnorm(100,3,1),
                           rnorm(100,3,1), rnorm(100,1,1), rnorm(100,2,1),
                           rnorm(100,2,1), rnorm(100,3,1), rnorm(100,1,1)),
                 class = c(rep("c1",100), rep("c2",100), rep("c3",100),
                           rep("c2",100), rep("c4",100), rep("c1",100),
                           rep("c4",100), rep("c3",100), rep("c2",100)),
                 group = c(rep("g1",300), rep("g2",300), rep("g3",300)))

df$class <- factor(df$class, levels =c("c1","c2","c3","c4"))
df$group <- factor(df$group, levels =c("g1","g2","g3"))
```

Not each group in the data has the same classes, or put differently each group has a subset of all classes.

I'm trying to generate `R` `plotly` density curves for each group, color-coded by class, and then combine them all to a single plot using `plotly`'s `subplot` function.

This is what I'm doing:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)


set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(value = c(rnorm(100,1,1), rnorm(100,2,1), rnorm(100,3,1),
                           rnorm(100,3,1), rnorm(100,1,1), rnorm(100,2,1),
                           rnorm(100,2,1), rnorm(100,3,1), rnorm(100,1,1)),
                 class = c(rep("c1",100), rep("c2",100), rep("c3",100),
                           rep("c2",100), rep("c4",100), rep("c1",100),
                           rep("c4",100), rep("c3",100), rep("c2",100)),
                 group = c(rep("g1",300), rep("g2",300), rep("g3",300)))

df$class <- factor(df$class, levels =c("c1","c2","c3","c4"))
df$group <- factor(df$group, levels =c("g1","g2","g3"))

plot.list <- lapply(c("g1","g2","g3"), function(g){
  density.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(dplyr::filter(df, group == g)$class),function(l)
    ggplot_build(ggplot(dplyr::filter(df, group == g & class == l),aes(x=value))+geom_density(adjust=1,colour="#A9A9A9"))$data[[1]] %>%
      dplyr::select(x,y) %>% dplyr::mutate(class = l)))
  plot_ly(x = density.df$x, y = density.df$y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',color = density.df$class) %>%
    layout(title=g,xaxis = list(zeroline = F), yaxis = list(zeroline = F))
})
subplot(plot.list,nrows=length(plot.list),shareX=T)
```

Which gives:
[image]

The problems I'd like to fix are:

1. Have the legend appear only once (right now it repeats for each group) merging all classes
2. Have the title appear in each of the subplots rather than only for the last plot at is it is now. (I know that I could simply have the group name as the x-axis titles but I'd rather save that space because in reality I have more than 3 groups)

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2744) a related FR for plotly.js and [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1873) a related issue regarding r-plotly can be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `plot_ly()` it's a little tricky, at least if you'd like to stick with using the `color` argument to generate multiple traces from the data.

You need to define a `legendgroup` taking into account your class variable.
This `legendgroup` however doesn't merge the legend items into one (it just groups them).

Accordingly to avoid duplicated entries in the legend you need to set `showlegend = FALSE` for the traces you want to hide (regarding the legend).

**Edit:** this can be done via `plotly::style`:

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(value = c(rnorm(100,1,1), rnorm(100,2,1), rnorm(100,3,1),
                           rnorm(100,3,1), rnorm(100,1,1), rnorm(100,2,1),
                           rnorm(100,2,1), rnorm(100,3,1), rnorm(100,1,1)),
                 class = c(rep("c1",100), rep("c2",100), rep("c3",100),
                           rep("c2",100), rep("c4",100), rep("c1",100),
                           rep("c4",100), rep("c3",100), rep("c2",100)),
                 group = c(rep("g1",300), rep("g2",300), rep("g3",300)))

df$class <- factor(df$class, levels =c("c1","c2","c3","c4"))
df$group <- factor(df$group, levels =c("g1","g2","g3"))

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

plot.list <- lapply(c("g1","g2","g3"), function(g){
  density.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(dplyr::filter(df, group == g)$class),function(l)
    ggplot_build(ggplot(dplyr::filter(df, group == g & class == l),aes(x=value))+geom_density(adjust=1,colour="#A9A9A9"))$data[[1]] %>%
      dplyr::select(x,y) %>% dplyr::mutate(class = l)))

  p <- plot_ly(data = density.df, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', color = ~class, legendgroup = ~class, showlegend = FALSE) %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(zeroline = F), yaxis = list(zeroline = FALSE)) %>%
    add_annotations(
      text = g,
      x = 0.5,
      y = 1.1,
      yref = "paper",
      xref = "paper",
      xanchor = "middle",
      yanchor = "top",
      showarrow = FALSE,
      font = list(size = 15)
    )
  if(g == "g1"){
    p <- style(p, showlegend = TRUE)
  } else if(g == "g2"){
    p <- style(p, showlegend = TRUE, traces = 3)
  } else {
    p <- style(p, showlegend = FALSE)
  }
  p
})

subplot(plot.list, nrows = length(plot.list), shareX = TRUE) # margin = 0.01
```

---

**Initial answer:**
This can be done by setting `showlegend = TRUE` only for the first plot and force it to display all available classes via dummy data. Please see the following:

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(value = c(rnorm(100,1,1), rnorm(100,2,1), rnorm(100,3,1),
                           rnorm(100,3,1), rnorm(100,1,1), rnorm(100,2,1),
                           rnorm(100,2,1), rnorm(100,3,1), rnorm(100,1,1)),
                 class = c(rep("c1",100), rep("c2",100), rep("c3",100),
                           rep("c2",100), rep("c4",100), rep("c1",100),
                           rep("c4",100), rep("c3",100), rep("c2",100)),
                 group = c(rep("g1",300), rep("g2",300), rep("g3",300)))

df$class <- factor(df$class, levels =c("c1","c2","c3","c4"))
df$group <- factor(df$group, levels =c("g1","g2","g3"))

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

plot.list <- lapply(c("g1","g2","g3"), function(g){
  density.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(dplyr::filter(df, group == g)$class),function(l)
    ggplot_build(ggplot(dplyr::filter(df, group == g & class == l),aes(x=value))+geom_density(adjust=1,colour="#A9A9A9"))$data[[1]] %>%
      dplyr::select(x,y) %>% dplyr::mutate(class = l)))
  
  p <- plot_ly(data = density.df, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', color = ~class, legendgroup = ~class, showlegend = FALSE) %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(zeroline = F), yaxis = list(zeroline = FALSE)) %>%
    add_annotations(
      text = g,
      x = 0.5,
      y = 1.1,
      yref = "paper",
      xref = "paper",
      xanchor = "middle",
      yanchor = "top",
      showarrow = FALSE,
      font = list(size = 15)
    )
  if(g == "g1"){
    dummy_df <- data.frame(class = unique(df$class))
    dummy_df$x <- density.df$x[1]
    dummy_df$y <- density.df$y[1]
    p <- add_trace(p, data = dummy_df, x = ~x, y = ~y, color = ~class, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", showlegend = TRUE, legendgroup = ~class, hoverinfo = 'none')
  }
  p
})

subplot(plot.list, nrows = length(plot.list), shareX = TRUE)
```

[image: result]

Another approach (avoiding the dummy data workaround) would be to create each trace in a loop (or via lapply) and control it's legend-visibilty according to the first occurrence of the item.

Furthermore, I think it should be possible to control the visibilty of legend items using `?plotly::style`. However, I can't control it for single traces currently. I filed an issue [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1873).

Regarding the titles for the subplots please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49524730/9841389).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

ggplotly(
  ggplot(df, aes(x=value, col = class)) + 
  geom_density(adjust=1) + 
  facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 1) +
    theme_minimal() + 
    theme(legend.position = 'top')
)
```

which gives me the following plot
[image]