# How to group datapoints independently from coloring in plotly without splitting the legend?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I want to plot multiple points connected by lines in plotly. While there should be exactly one line per id-group (as defined in the dataset), the color of those lines should depend on a different column in the data.

Consider this example data:

```r
 df <- data.frame(
   x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
   y = c(0,0,3,1,4,5),
   id= c(1,1,2,2,3,3), # defines belonging to line
   group = c("A","A","A","A","B","B") # defines color of the point and line
 )
```

if I plot it this way, it kind of works:

```r
 plot_ly(df,type = "scatter", mode = "lines+markers",
         x = ~x,
         y = ~y,
         split = ~id,
         color = ~group)
```

Unfortunately, the legend is also split along `split` and `color`:[image: Plot with split legend]

I only want it to display the color part of the legend. In this example case the legend would only have two entries. One for "A" and one for "B".

**Is there a simple way to do this that I am not seeing here?**

Addendum: An id is always linked to one group only. There are no `id` values, that are shared bewtween multiple different `group` values

Comment: Could you supply the code to generate the plot?

Comment: Sry. Totally forgot the line. I edited my question accordingly

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plotly's `color` parameter will always create traces based on the provided data (just like `split`, but with `colors` mapped).

However, we can combine the separate legend items via `legendgroup` and display only one of them:

```
library(plotly)

DF <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  y = c(0,0,3,1,4,5),
  id= c(1,1,2,2,3,3), # defines belonging to line
  group = c("A","A","A","A","B","B") # defines color of the point and line
)

fig <- plot_ly(DF, type = "scatter", mode = "lines+markers",
               x = ~x,
               y = ~y,
               split = ~id,
               color = ~group,
               name = ~group,
               legendgroup = ~group) %>%
       layout(showlegend = TRUE) %>%
       style(showlegend = FALSE, traces = 1)

fig
```

[image: result]

Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63627563/merging-legends-in-plotly-subplot/63629831#63629831) for a more general approach.

Comment: I've tried your approach along with your more global approach, but it doesn't seem to work in my case. I've opened a topic here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76803792/group-legend-and-colors-plotly-r