# Group legend and colors plotly R

Tags: r, plotly

Based on the reproducible example below, I would like `Variable1` to have the same color on the plot instead of 2, and same for `Variable2`. Then, the legend would need to show 2 lines only : one for each color, instead of 4 for now.

How can I achieve this ?

[image]

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(Date = c(seq.Date(as.Date("2022-01-01"),
                                   as.Date("2022-06-30"),
                                   by = "day"),
                          seq.Date(as.Date("2023-01-01"),
                                   as.Date("2023-06-30"),
                                   by = "day")),
                 Period = rep(c(1,2), each = 181),
                 Variable1 = runif(362),
                 Variable2 = c(rep(0.4, 181), rep(0.6, 181)))


plot_ly(data = df, x = ~Date, y = ~Variable1, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", name = "Variable 1", split = ~Period) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Date, y = ~Variable2, name = "Variable 2", split = ~Period)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set one color for two traces, you can use the argument `color`, along with the function `I()`, such as `color = I('#1f77b4')`.

Because you used `split`, you created a new trace, which is why you see four legend entries. If you want the two periods two have one legend entry, you can group them with `legendgroup`, where you can assign and character name you would like (this is what you'll see in the legend).

To make sure only one legend item is shown per group, you need to change the parameter `showlegend` for one of each legend group. Because there isn't a straightforward method of entering multiple `showlegend` in a single call for a trace, I've created `fixer()`. All this function does is change the 2d and 4th trace to `showlegend = F`.

```
fixer <- function(plt) {  # change legend for 2 of 4 traces
  plt <- plotly_build(plt)
  plt$x$data[[2]]$showlegend <- plt$x$data[[4]]$showlegend <- F
  plt
}

plot_ly(data = df, x = ~Date, y = ~Variable1, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", 
        name = "Variable 1", split = ~Period,  
        color = I('#1f77b4'), legendgroup = "Variable 1") %>%     # <<--- I'm new!
  add_trace(x = ~Date, y = ~Variable2, name = "Variable 2", split = ~Period, 
            color = I('#ff7f0e'), legendgroup = "Variable 2") %>% # <<--- I'm new! 
  fixer()
```

[image]