# How to hide the (interpolated) fill in plotly when there are NA values in the data? (Using R)

Tags: r, plotly, na, r-plotly

I am trying to plot a line graph with fill and NA values. Plotly automatically fills the part with NA values where I want it to be empty. What is the best way to get the correct graph?

It is not an option to set the NA values to 0. I am also using a hoover and do not want to have a result of 0 while hovering over the line.

Example R data + code:

```
library(plotly)

set.seed(1)
A = data.frame(x = 1900:2000, value=cumsum(rnorm(101)))
A[40:70, 2:3] = NA

fig <- plot_ly(x = A$x, y = A$value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', fill = 'tozeroy')
fig
```

Result:
[image]

Desired Result:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could `split` the data into separate traces to achive this:

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)
A = data.frame(x = 1900:2000, value = cumsum(rnorm(101)))
A[40:70, 2] = NA

setDT(A)
A[, id := rleid(is.na(value))]

fig <- plot_ly(
    data = A,
    x = ~ x,
    y = ~ value,
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'lines',
    fill = 'tozeroy',
    split = ~ id,
    color = I("#1f77b4"),
    showlegend = FALSE
  )
fig
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for the great workaround. The graph looks like my desired result. Unfortunately my hoover and legend now show all the traces. Is there a way to show it as a single trace?

Comment: You can assign both traces to the same legendgroup and hide one of the legend items. This strategy is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63629831/9841389).