# R plotly pie chart with subplots

Tags: r, plotly, pie-chart, subplot

I'm trying to produce an `R` `plotly` `pie chart` `subplot` with two pies with a title for each. I followed the example under the `Subplots` header in [this tutorial](https://plotly.com/r/pie-charts/), only plotting two out of the three pies and adding a title to each:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

fig <- plot_ly()
fig <- fig %>% add_pie(data = count(diamonds, cut), labels = ~cut, values = ~n, textinfo='label+percent', showlegend=F,
                       name = "Cut", domain = list(x = c(0, 0.4), y = c(0.4, 1))) %>%
  layout(title="Cut")
fig <- fig %>% add_pie(data = count(diamonds, color), labels = ~color, values = ~n, textinfo='label+percent', showlegend=F,
                       name = "Color", domain = list(x = c(0.6, 1), y = c(0.4, 1))) %>%
  layout(title="Color")
```

Which gives:
[image]

It looks similar to the problem of having multiple titles when using the `plotly` `subplot` function (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285729/how-to-give-subtitles-for-subplot-in-plot-ly-using-r)), but in this case subplot is not explicitly called so I'm not sure what would be the equivalent solution here.

Answer (score 2):

The `title` argument needs to be in the `trace` call:

```
fig <- plot_ly()
fig <- fig %>% add_pie(data = count(diamonds, cut), labels = ~cut, values = ~n, textinfo='label+percent', showlegend=F, title="Cut",
                       name = "Cut", domain = list(x = c(0, 0.4), y = c(0.4, 1)))
fig <- fig %>% add_pie(data = count(diamonds, color), labels = ~color, values = ~n, textinfo='label+percent', showlegend=F, title="Color",
                       name = "Color", domain = list(x = c(0.6, 1), y = c(0.4, 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: How can their position be adjusted?